# Text element not showing on SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a bubblechart using D3 and put a text inside the bubble.  I've checked through a lot of examples and understand that the HTML DOM should look like a group tag surrounding the circle and text tag 
which I believe I have in my jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q4nszx34/

I attempted to make the text appear in the same area as the bubble via:

```
circles.append("text")  
       .attr("dx", -10)
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .text(function (d) {
          return d.key;
        })
        .style("stroke", "gray");
```

However, the text element's location is not at the same location as my bubble, and I'm not sure how to get the bubble's location to set the text's location.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ticked` function, translate your group elements:

```
circles.attr("transform", function(d){
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
```

That way, both the `<circle>` and the `<text>` elements will move together.

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k45oaztv/

Comment: ah i see, so instead of selecting just my text group, I'd select a larger group and move them together? Thanks for the info!

Comment: sorry for the followup question, but when I add multiple bubbles, the text starts to be overlapped by the bubbles. Is there a way to make text appear in the front of bubbles?